# ehcache - any solution to access expired element content?

Tags: java, ehcache

I am using ehcache to cache data, usually 24h expiration time. I want to take element individual actions at the time an element expires. Therefore i neee the element content. I registered a CacheEventListener in order to get a notification (notifyElementExpired) in case of element expiration. Unfortunately at notification time only the key is known - content is already discarded, which is kind of painful!

Any solution to access element content at expiration time?

Answer (score 1):

You can create your custom eviction `Policy` that delegates all calls to the actual policy you use. In your implementation you need to override `selectedBasedOnPolicy` method, where you can  specify your action:

```
class MyEvictionPolicy extends LruPolicy { // you can subclass FifoPolicy or LfuPolicy here
    @Override
    public Element selectedBasedOnPolicy(Element[] sampledElements, Element justAdded) {
        Element candidate = super.selectedBasedOnPolicy(sampledElements, justAdded);
        if (candidate.isExpired()) {
            // perform your action here
        }
        return candidate;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Look at [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13942814/ehcache-based-on-date/13952527#13952527) to a similar question. You could stick in some code inside `isExpired` method and act accordingly if the result is `true`.

And yes, this is probably not the cleanest approach but it should work.