# Cache eviction at particular time of the day and not through TTL

Tags: spring, guava, ehcache, gemfire

Please let me know if cache eviction can be done at particular time of the day instead of TTL. I am using spring framework so if any API provides this feature then I can use this API by plugging into Spring. 
I did run through search mechanism if similar question has been asked but failed to find any prior question.

If similar question has been asked please let me know the link.

Thanks, Amitabh

Answer (score 1):

According to GemFire docs:

> You configure for eviction based on entry count, percentage of
>   available heap, and absolute memory usage. You also configure what to
>   do when you need to evict: destroy entries or overflow them to disk.
>   See Persistence and Overflow.

http://gemfire.docs.pivotal.io/latest/userguide/index.html#developing/eviction/configuring_data_eviction.html

But you may be able to get something closer to what you need through Custom expiration.  Please check the following link:

http://gemfire.docs.pivotal.io/latest/userguide/index.html#developing/expiration/configuring_data_expiration.html

Comment: Thanks a lot Markito for the quick reply, I am going to do a shortly POC based on your recommendations and revert back to you ASAP.

Answer (score 1):

[Ehcache expiration](http://ehcache.org/documentation/2.8/recipes/expiration) does not offer such a feature out of the box.

You still have some options:

- Configure the TTL when creating the Element with a computed value.
- Use [refresh-ahead](http://ehcache.org/apidocs/2.9/net/sf/ehcache/constructs/refreshahead/package-summary.html) or even better [scheduled refresh ahead](http://terracotta.org/generated/4.2.0/html/bmm-all/index.html#page/BigMemory_Max_Documentation_Set/co-refresh_scheduled_refresh_ahead.html)
- Have a look at the [following question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13942814/ehcache-based-on-date). Note that this may not work with all configurations as sometimes the Element gets re-created internally.

Comment: Thanks a lot Markito for the quick reply, I am going to do a shortly POC based on your recommendations and revert back to you ASAP.